# How do I run a command that can take an unspecified number of env arguments?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

```rust
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    Command::new("sudo")
        .arg("apt")
        .arg(&args[0].to_lowercase())
        .arg(&args[EVERY OTHER ARGUMENT THE USER INPUTTED]);
}
```

As you see in the code I want to have every argument the user inputted (after the 1st argument) to run but I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: rust noob: Wouldn't slices work? Seems slices implement IntoIterator (as required by args() here), so would .args(&args[1..]) work? No need for a mutable Vec<T> then

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun Nope that spits out a bunch of errors

Comment: @SmushyTaco it's not helpful to say "spits out a bunch of errors". Benjamin's suggestion above is correct. Using a slice will work here. You probably have some syntax error in how you're constructing the slice. Or maybe some other issue with how you're instantiating the `Command` object. If you told us what the errors were, we could suggest the right syntax. But since you haven't told us, we have to wait and see if you reply again with more information.

Comment: @JackO'Connor My bad I read it as arg.(&args[1..]) not args([&args[1..). I already found a solution anyways so it's all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the first element from the argument list and then give it to the args as a complete vector reference like following:

```rust
let mut args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

if !args.is_empty() {
    let first_arg = args.remove(0);
    Command::new("sudo")
        .arg("apt")
        .arg(&first_arg.to_lowercase())
        .args(&args);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ec3b70d6fd2e7606436e355100ae3b8)

Comment: That requires hardcoding all the values in the args vec and in my situation there's an infinite amount of environment variables that can be inputted.

Comment: @SmushyTaco, I just created the arg vec to show the usage that works in Playground. In real case you get your args vector from environment for sure

Comment: Same question I posted below the question: Could this be done without the mutable Vec<T> and by using slices instead? args[0] and args[1..]? (I am clueless about Rust, but it seems to be possible based on the docs I read)

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun a `Vec` coereces to a slice. But how do you want to initialize the slice? That's why @Webstrix used a `Vec` instead.

Comment: @hellow I'm asking if https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=035e2c22548c0e54f1bc9ad7789f2fa7 would work

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun, In my opinion it should also work.

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun have a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args and tell me if it works ;) You even could use a `HashSet` or whatever struct implements `IntoIterator`.

Comment: @hellow I'm .. basically clueless about Rust. I did try to compile it and it seemed okay. The difference? I guess .. it just keeps one Vec, unmodified, with a slice as a view. Same same, chalk it up to curiosity of a bystander :) It just feels like the natural 'all but the first in a Vec' expression the OP was asking for to me.

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun https://play.integer32.com/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ac9c18b04e3a29bb3df641bc8c341d02

Answer (score 10):

Rather than collect the `env::args()` iterator into a vector, then modify the vector, you can directly use the original iterator:

```
let mut args = env::args();
if let Some(first_arg) = args.next() {
    Command::new("sudo")
        .arg("apt")
        .arg(first_arg.to_lowercase())
        .args(args);
}
```